# Uncaught TypeError: textLocation[p].find is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have an `<ul>` with unknown numbers of `<li>` elements inside.
Every `<li>` elements could have or not `$('p.have')` element with some text.
I want to receive a text from every `$('p.have')` elements and if there is no `$('p.have')` we have receive an empty string.
Possible example of `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from first</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from second</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="notHave">Not our text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from fourth</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from five</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Resul:
    'Text from first', 
    'Text from second', 
    ' ', 
    'Text from fourth'

I'm using following script:

```
var textLocation = $('ul li');
var  mytext = [];
function findText (){
    for (var p = 0 ; p < textLocation.length; p++) {
        if(textLocation[p].find('p.have')) {
            mytext.push($(this).text());
        } else { mytext.push(' ');}
    }


}

findText();
console.log(mytext);
```

but I am receiving following error

> Uncaught TypeError: textLocation[p].find is not a function

Can anybody help me to solve the problem

Comment: what is the value of `textLocation`? how did you intialized this value?

Comment: Hi, yhank you for your question.
I have edited my question please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to receive a text from every $('p.have') elements and if there
>   is no $('p.have') we have receive an empty string.

Try this simple approach

```
var mytext = [];
$('ul li').each( function(){
  if ( $(this).find( "p.have" ).length > 0 )
  {
    mytext.push($(this).find( "p.have" ).text());
  }
  else
  {
    mytext.push($(this).find( "p.notHave" ).text());
  }
});
```

Comment: This should be the proper answer, because the others so far do not look for the `p` specifically under list items. So what happens if you have other paragraphs aside from these?

Answer (score 0):

use this , try to use forEach on array of element ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from first</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from second</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- <p class="have"></p> -->
            <p class="notHave">Not our text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from fourth</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from five</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script>
function findText (){
var string = "";
$.each($('p.have'),function(index,ele){
    string += $(ele).html() + ",";
})
console.log(string.slice(0,-1))
}
findText();
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer.
I receiving the same result [link](http://prntscr.com/euzi9v)

Comment: have a look i have try it with $.each, looks like javascript giving error

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:(Check this new update) :)** 
Have a look at this :)
You didnt defined `textLocation` look at my code hence you got  `textLocation[p].find is not a function` there.

```js
function findText(){
  var textLocation = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for(var i = 0; i < textLocation.length; i++){
     //do something to each div like
     if(textLocation[i].classList.contains("have"))
     {
      console.log(textLocation[i].innerHTML); 
     }else if(textLocation[i].classList.contains("notHave")){
      console.log(''); 
     }
     
  }
    
}           
findText();
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from first</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from second</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- <p class="have"></p> -->
            <p class="notHave">Not our text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from fourth</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="have">Text from five</p>
            <!-- <p class="notHave"></p> -->
        </li>
        
        
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for reply.
Sorry, I really forget to specify textLocation here but I have it in my script.
In your function we receiving "Not our text" as a 3rd parameter.
But we have to receive an empty string.
Any way thank you for your answer. I understood how to specify my question)

Comment: Hi, glad you understood. Check the new update i created. This will solve your prolem.